# Realm Swift 0.92.3 "Run Script Phase" not working

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

Trying to use the new realm-swift-0.92.3, I can't get this “Run Script Phase” to work. I follow the instructions from [here](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

My Run-Script entry according to the the instructions is (see image below):

[image]

Unfortunately, I still get the following error message while trying to compile (see below). What could still be wrong ???

bash: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppglnkfueqyjbdhurfurfkip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: **No such file or directory**

My Framework-Search-Paths is also set, as follows:
/Users/XXX/.../MyApp/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks

I appreciate any help on this !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your framework is added to the Embedded Binaries and Embed Frameworks.

While this is the first step that you're supposed to do: "Go to your Xcode project’s “General” settings. Drag RealmSwift.framework from the ios/ or osx/ directory to the “Embedded Binaries” section. Make sure Copy items if needed is selected and click Finish.", for some reason it didn't add it there for me, just to the project.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! The "dragging" did it for me - plus, one does not seem to be allowed to create "folder-groups" with the RealSwift.framework !!  As soon as the RealmSwift.framework is moved to a folder-group - the "Embedded Binary" turns RED! Therefore, your solution of "dragging" (without my moving it to a folder-group) did it for me and it compiles now !I Thanks again !

Comment: As [Kruherson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3692170/kruherson) mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269289/watchkit-realm-0-92-3), it is better to use CocoaPods instead of adding the ream-framework directly. The reason seems to be that your app might be rejected by Apple otherwise...

Answer (score 32):

Make sure that in the Build Phases *Run Script* is after *Embed Frameworks*. I got the build errors when *Run Script* was before *Embed Frameworks*.
[image]

Comment: This helped me. Thanks. But its looks strange may be an XCode bug I think.

Comment: How you guys found such tricks?? Why there are no proper documentation for such kind of solutions? It works perfectly..Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem. In fact this makes perfect sense ... Can not run the script before importing it into the app

Comment: How should it be "after"? The sorting is fixed, I can not change Xcode ?! What do you mean by after????

Answer (score 7):

For those who tried everything and still not working - this worked for me:

1) Go over `Xcode` where you see the error and copy this portion of the directory where it says no such file or directory: 
Using example above: `Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAppglnkfueqyjbdhurfurfkip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`

2)Copy that and place it on the top right of your MAC to search for that directory

3)Once you found that, you gonna go to that directory and find an application that is named exactly as your app(i.e MyApp) and is going to have like an invalid white circle with a line across it.

4) Right click that and go to show package contents.

5)You going to find a folder named Frameworks there.

6)Go ahead and drop both `Realm.framework` & `RealmSwift.framework`

7)Build should succeed in `Xcode` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the Build Phases Run Script is after Embed Frameworks. I got the build errors when Run Script was before Embed Frameworks.

Comment: Wow, that's what was wrong with mine and it set me back hours trying to debug! Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a different bash script running. After I changed the order (placed realm's one before) it worked