# Watchkit & Realm 0.92.3

Tags: ios, watchkit, realm

The Swift integration of a new Realm-DB (realm 0.92.3) under Xcode 6.3 and iOS10.10.3 basically works for the iPhone (not for the Apple-Watch yet). The integration of the same realm-framework under Watchkit (i.e. Apple-Watch) does not work yet.

The RealmSwift.framework is integrated (dragged into) the Embedded-Binaries as described [here1](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226810/realm-swift-0-92-3-run-script-phase-not-working/30230180#30230180). 
See screenshot below :

[image]

When running the Watchkit-App with the simulator the following error occurs :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3FE99-9-4C4C2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8B4-DF19F34-222973/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp WatchKit Extension.appex/MyApp WatchKit Extension
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

What is still wrong ???

The Framework-Search-Path of the main-app is set. The ones for MyApp Watchkit Extension and MyApp Watchkit App are not set. Setting them does not change the above error. What is still missing ???

Comment: Do you have any swift files in your App Extension / main app? If not, `swift-stdlib-tool` won't copy over the swift runtime dylibs, even if you have a framework that requires them.

Comment: Yes, I do have swift-files in both (i.e. App Extension and main-app)

Comment: I finally found a solution: Start over again with a new project (identical bundle-name) and copy all relevant storyboard- swiftFiles, frameworks, etc etc from a previously made project-copy step-by-step into the new project. That way, my watchKit starts working with the simulator ! It is, at least, unfortunate not to know what exactly was missing before !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use CocoaPods.

I did it like you did, with dynamic frameworks, but when I try to submit my application to iTunes Connect using Xcode's Organizer, I could not because of the nested frameworks. Realm.framework is inside RealmSwift.framework, and that is not okay with Apple. So I try and try but nothing helped…

Then I used CocoaPods and everything worked as it should.

Here are instructions for CocoaPods installation:

```
Install CocoaPods 0.37.1 or later ([sudo] gem install cocoapods).
In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! and pod 'RealmSwift' to your main and test targets.
From the command line, run pod install.
Use the .xcworkspace file generated by CocoaPods to work on your project!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Kruherson ! That is a great help. I will have a look at CocoaPods like you recommended.

Comment: Just another question: Having done the CocoaPods installation and opening the resulting MyApp.xcworkspace, it all seems to work, except: The "import RealmSwift" is no longer working. What do I need to place instead ??

Comment: You don't need to import RealmSwift anymore :)

Comment: If I comment-out all the "import RealmSwift" then I get plenty of errors (i.e. any realm-code is not recognized, such as for example Object, Realm, NotificationToken etc). Can you please tell me how your Podfile looked like ? And also how your MyApp-Bridging-Header.h file looked like ? And maybe also if I have to add all the new Pods-MyApp-xy schemas that seem to be there?? Not sure how I can make this get to work...

Comment: Do I still need to import any RealmFramework after having done the "pod install" ??

Comment: I added the "import RealmSwift" again and now it is working with the cocoapods !! It seems that my 'swift-file with the realm-object definition' needs the "import RealmSwift" since it is used in two locations, 1. in the "MyApp" and 2. in the "MyApp WatchKit Extension". The second one I never got to work without the "import" statement. Do you have any other suggestion ??

Comment: I am using Realm only on iPhone app, not in WatchKit Extension app. When I need something from database I call "handleWatchKitExtensionRequest" in iPhone app and send back a reply to watch. I Didn't try using Realm directly on WatchKit Extension app.

Comment: Thank you Kruherson! Ahh, that explains it. You are right, only iPhone-App plus Realm (doing it with Cocoapods) does not seem to need the "import RealmSwift". However, I could not get it to work without it as for the MyApp WatchKit Extension.... Do you know why by chance ?

Answer (score 1):

This Podfile finally did it for me (see below). Everything worked after that...
To install just open a terminal, go to your App's folder (where you place the Podfile) and type

```
pod install
```

After that make sure to open from now on the "MyApp.xcworkspace" (no longer "MyApp.xcodeproj") and you are all set !

Here is the podfile that worked :

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.3'

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.93.2'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end
```