# RealmSwift (0.92.3) and provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

The following error-message occurs when I try to run my watchkit app with my iPhone device (i.e. simulator runs fine) :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CCC-B93-89-4E6/MyApp.app/MyApp

Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9CC8D-43AE7-F8E/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm:

code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C98D-435D-A8E6/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'
(lldb)
```

Any idea what there is to do ??? Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to create a new "Run Script Phase" in the app's target as described in the [realm.io](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries) page:

```
"If using Realm in an iOS project, create a new “Run Script Phase” in your
app’s target’s “Build Phases” and paste the following snippet in the script
text field:

bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/RealmSwift.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"

This step is required to work around an App Store submission bug when
archiving universal binaries."
```

Here is a screenshot on how to find in Xcode-menu and how it eventually looks like !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Kruherson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692170/kruherson) recommends, that you use CocoaPods. [Check this post...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269289/watchkit-realm-0-92-3/30327792#30327792)

Thanks to [Kruherson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692170/kruherson) - we know now, that there seems to be a problem later on during app-revision in the app-store with the current solution given from the official realm.io [Swift-documentation](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) page !

Here is instruction for CocoaPods installation

```
Install CocoaPods 0.37.1 or later ([sudo] gem install cocoapods).
In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! and pod 'RealmSwift' to your main and test targets.
From the command line, run pod install.
Use the .xcworkspace file generated by CocoaPods to work on your project!
```