# Import RealmSwift no longer working using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

The CocoaPods installation of the RealmSwift [Kruherson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692170/kruherson) recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269289/watchkit-realm-0-92-3/30327792#30327792)  (or also is recommended from the realm.io page [here](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)) basically works - however there is one problem that is remaining in my App using Swift 0.92.3:

The following import is no longer recognized !

```
import RealmSwift
```

What do I still need to do in order to make CocoaPods work under Swift ?

Here is the content of my Podfile used :

```
platform :ios, '8.3'
use_frameworks!

xcodeproj '/Users/XXX/.../MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
end
```

Here a screenshot of my Xcode project (only Pods part) looks like after the "pod install" :

[image]

There are a few "red things" - might the problem lie here or what do I still miss ?

What do I need to do in order to get `import RealmSwift` working again ??

Comment: Red typically implies that the file isn't located where Xcode expects it to be located.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I am fully aware of that! However, I thought that installing RealmSwift with CocoaPods would handle this... Any suggestion on how to proceed in order to get the "import RealmSwift" working again ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CocoaPods and Realm in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428046/cocoapods-and-realm-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The "red" color of all the Pod-frameworks is no harm! The frameworks are not physically there - therefore Xcode cannot change the color. It, for sure, does not indicate a mistake here...

However, the Podfile above is not the right one if you want to use your "MyApp WatchKit Extension". The correct one is:

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.3'

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Also, it is important that you still "import RealmSwift" in your Realm-Object definition(s) as can be seen in an example below:

[image]

Also, if you intend to use your Realm-Object in two targets (i.e. "MyApp" and "MyApp WatchKit Extension"), make sure you select both the corresponding targets in the target selection pane of your RealmObject.swift file (see image below):

[image]