# CocoaPods and Realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

Using Xcode-6.3.1, iOS-8.3 and MacOS-10.10.3, I am trying to use RealmSwift (0.92.3) and CocoaPods 0.37.1

I use the following procedure :

1. install cocoapods (in terminal):

   ```
    $ sudo gem install cocoapods
   ```
2. Create new Xcode project (named MyApp)
3. Create Podfile

   ```
   platform :ios, '8.3'
   use_frameworks!

   target 'MyApp' do
     pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
   end

   target 'MyAppTests' do
     pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
   end
   ```
4. Place the Podfile in the MyApp folder (next to MyApp.xcodeproj)
5. Download the newest Realm (0.92.3 from [here](https://realm.io/)) (i.e. Swift version)

   - unzip it
   - go to /ios folder
   - copy RealmSwift.framework also to your MyApp-project folder

(after Point 4 and 5 you end up like in the picture here)

[image]

6. Inside a terminal, go to your MyApp-folder and type

   ```
       pod install
   ```
7. After pod-install, I end up with the following text inside the terminal:

[image]

8. After that, I simply open the new MyApp.xcworkspace

It basically looks ok - except: NO FRAMEWORK SEEMS TO BE FOUND !! (see screenshot below)...

What am I still missing ????

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import RealmSwift no longer working using CocoaPods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425854/import-realmswift-no-longer-working-using-cocoapods)

Comment: @gyer - Please don't indiscriminately add [ios] as a tag to any question about CocoaPods. CocoaPods can be used for OS X, as well, so it's not exclusively for iOS. We've been receiving complaints about some of these edits.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found out that the "red" colored missing frameworks are no harm. Using CocoaPods these frameworks are not physically there - therefore Xcode cannot change the color. It, for sure, does not indicate a mistake here...

THREFORE THE ABOVE WORKFLOW (pt 1-8) IS CORRECT !

However, the Podfile above is not the right one if you want to use your "MyApp WatchKit Extension". The correct one is:

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.3'

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Also, it is important that you still "import RealmSwift" in your Realm-Object definition(s) as can be seen in an example below:

[image]

Also, if you intend to use your Realm-Object in two targets (i.e. "MyApp" and "MyApp WatchKit Extension"), make sure you select both the corresponding targets in the target selection pane of your RealmObject.swift file (see image below):

[image]