# What does the Podfile for a WatchKit Extension App look like?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchkit, realm

What does the cocoapod **Podfile** for a WatchKit Extension App look like ??

More precisely, I am trying to use RealmSwift integration.

```
(using MacOS10.10.3, Xcode-6.3.2, iOS-8.3, CocoaPods-0.37.1, RealmSwift-0.92.3)
```

The Podfile that I am currently using looks like this (...not working yet!!! ...since WatchKit Extension does not recognize the Realm-objects...):

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '8.3'

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
      pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 0.92.3'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end

link_with ['MyApp', 'MyApp WatchKit Extension']
```

Comment: Why did you post this question twice?

Comment: Good question! Well, first of all, I guess "better twice than nothing". And second of all, the very similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434726/watchkit-extension-not-working-under-cocoapods) was more prone to the fact that I am using the Realm-Object (NameEntry) in both targets (i.e. MyApp and MyApp WatchKit Extension). Therefore, the double entries... This post here is simply the clarification of how such a Podfile looks like ! Any idea ? The other post shall go a bit further and asking also about target-settings...